# How to get information from a webpage, but not all?

Tags: android

I am retrying to retreive just the text and the image  from this wiki page.

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Where_the_Red_Fern_Grows

I will have a news feed, and when i item is clicked the url will be fetched. Intead of going to a the webpage through the browser, i would like to get the text and images and feed them into a textview and imageviews.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a couple of options.

- Host a intermediary site that parses the link and passes back the data you want.
- Get all of the page, and parse on the device.

Obviously parsing a huge page on the device will be far slower than parsing it on a webserver and serving just what you need.

Of course, if you are really in need of just the text and image, there is some help by using the mobile version of Wikipedia:
http://mobile.wikipedia.org
OR
http://en.m.wikipedia.org

The "mobile" version splits pages up and contains no graphics, but the "m" version is probably more along the lines of what you are looking for.

Here is the formatted page for "Where The Red Fern Grows":
http://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Where_the_Red_Fern_Grows

Comment: i dont want to do the mobile version of the webpage because wiki isnt the only page i will be using. So i will need to create or use a parser as you suggested. How do i go about getting/using one of these? http sax or dom? apache jericho?

Comment: How you implement that is up to you and your needs.  For most of my stuff these days I use a `LAMP` server and typically serve `JSON` for most of my needs, but it all really depends on what you're comfortable with.

Comment: Is there any tutorials or books that tell you how to use such?

Comment: These are the two pieces I would start looking at:

json_encode: http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-encode.php
DOM: http://www.php.net/manual/en/book.dom.php
A DOM Parser: http://simplehtmldom.sourceforge.net/